# How to convert an integer to ASCII in C?

Tags: c, string, integer, ascii

Hell there, I'm trying to convert an integer to ASCII string. Check the function below:

```
void Conv(uint16_t sValue, char *pBuffer) { // sValue = 6
int test = '0' + sValue; // test = 54 Which I assume is correct.. 
pBuffer[0] = test + '0'; // When I try to convert the result into a char and send through Pbuffer I get 119 ?
```

}

Okay, I this point I got really confused, where does 119 comes from? I would assume it will be converted again to ASCII, but why 119?
Anyway, any help will be appreciated!
The final goal is to receive a int number converted it to ASCII and send back as a string..

Comment: the ASCII value of the character '0' is 48
I don't seem to understand what do you mean by converting an int to ASCII and send it back as a string

Comment: Hi Gilad, no this is just to convert it '0' is not a number

Comment: ah well you shouldn't add '0' then, you add the value of 48 twice before assigning it to pBuffer[0]